# dhcp failed. apipa is being used

Tags: vlan, dhcp

I'm testing a network and I use the vlan among 20 vlan but in this packet tracer I just use 10 Vlan on my network,

In this case, I use the DHCP server on my multilayer switch, not on my router.

so on the port on multilayer swith to switch layer 2 I use:

```
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk
```

for the DHCP server on multilayer switch I use:

```
ip dhcp pool vlan1
network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.0.1
```

and the same for other vlan.

I have add the vlan and the IP address like on the picture

[image]

but when I config on the all switch layer 2,

on fa0/1 who connected to multilayerswitch I use:

```
switchport mode trunk
```

and port fa0/2-3 who connected to PC I use:

```
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan <VLANID>
! VLANID == VLAN for respective switch
```

But there's some thing weird,

On VLAN 1 and 2 it's almost connected and get the dhcp ip success but on the other PC I cannot get the DHCP IP it's remarks "dhcp failed. apipa is being used"

please help,

Comment: maybe u can attach .pkt please,

Comment: Did you configure VTP or add the VLANs to all the L2 switches? Run the following command on one of the L2 switches where it isn't working and edit it into the question: `sh interface trunk`

Comment: Try packet tracers simulation mode.

Comment: i faced the same issue with my lab, the problem it was the VLAN interfaces in the L3 switch, after that everything were working perfectly. thank you guys for your comments they were very useful.

Comment: I should check a few things:<br/>
<br/>
- if the access port are belongs to the desired vlan on L2 Switch<br/>
- if the desired VLANs are present on L2 Switch<br/>
- if the VLANs are allowed on trunk interface<br/>
- if the SVI's are up on Multilayer Switch<br/>
- and then fainally the DHCP pools<br/>
<br/>
let me know

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Friend use configuration as below as  you should have be sound basic knowledge

on router

```
Lab-R1> ena

Lab-R1# config t

Lab-R1(config)# ip dhcp pool myLAN

Lab-R1(dhcp-config)# network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0

Lab-R1(dhcp-config)# domain-name mydomain.lan

Lab-R1(dhcp-config)# default-router 192.168.0.1

Lab-R1(dhcp-config)# dns-server 192.168.0.2

Lab-R1(dhcp-config)# exit

Lab-R1(config)# ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.120
```

at L2 sw

create vlan as 1 to 20 everyone have ip address with in same range as specified in router with each vlan have four ip address

```
int vlan 1
ip address  192.168.0.5 255.255.255.0

int vlan 2
ip address  192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0

.
..
..
.
.

int vlan 20 ip address  192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0
```

it's working

Answer (score 0):

See i made a similar [topology](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B85TmH4wS9GSVnMxNEQtZ3hyc0E/view?usp=sharing) and uploaded to drive.

The ports connecting from to L3-sw to L2-sw and L2-sw to L3-sw both need to be trunked to carry all the vlans.

And the port connecting to pc should be access and assigned to the vlan you want.

Also create both the vlans on L3-sw along with the interfaces for those vlans.

If you want inter-vlan routing then also enable:

```
conf t 
ip routing
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check a few things:

- if the access port are belongs to the desired vlan on L2 Switch
- if the desired VLANs are present on L2 Switch
- if the VLANs are allowed on trunk interface
- if the SVI's are up on Multilayer Switch
- and then fainally the DHCP pools

If you have any other problem please attach the show running-config of the Multilayer Switch